# Undefined value in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have defined a function like `self.loadAffected = function(){ko.observable(true);}`

and trying to print on the another functions like

```
self.loadAffectedChanged = function() {
    // clear "Road Blocked" when Load Affected is selected
    **alert(self.loadAffected());**
    if (self.loadAffected === false)
        self.groupable(false);
    else
    // clear "Groupable" when Load Affected is cleared

        self.roadBlocked(false);
};
```

calling above function through HTML like

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="jqmChecked: loadAffected, click: loadAffectedChanged" 
                   name="load_affected" id="load_affected"/>
```

when im clicking on the check box it is throwing undefined as popup box,
[image]

Could somebody help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`self.loadAffected()` will always give you `undefined` because it's just a function that doesn't return anything. I'm not sure what the [custom binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) `jqmChecked` does, but I don't it's relevant to the issue.

You should change your code to:

```
self.loadAffected = ko.observable(true); // now loadAffected is an observable

self.loadAffectedChanged = function() {
    // you need to add the parentheses here to read the value of loadAffected observable
    if (self.loadAffected() === false)
        self.groupable(false);
    else
    // clear "Groupable" when Load Affected is cleared

     self.roadBlocked(false);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, But with above change it is always checking the else part only. Even we try with if (self.loadAffected() === true) it is going else part. could you provide any other suggestions?

Comment: Don't think it has anything to with the question. Must be some issue with your custom binding `jqmChecked`.